# Java spring-boot problem with access to pages

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a problem with spring-boot-security.
Problem: can't access /getuser (403 Forbidden)

WebConfig:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/styles/**", "/error").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/users", "/userlog").hasRole(AdminRoles.DEV.name())
                .antMatchers("/logs", "/updlog").hasAnyRole(AdminRoles.DEV.name(), AdminRoles.ADMIN.name())
                .antMatchers("/update", "/getuser", "/").hasAnyRole(AdminRoles.DEV.name(), AdminRoles.ADMIN.name(), 
                                                                                    AdminRoles.MODERATOR.name())
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                .formLogin();
    }
```

/getuser in controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/getuser")
    public String getuser(String userData, int server, Model model) throws SQLException, Exception{
        model.addAttribute("user", base.GetUser(userData, server));
        return "index";
    }
```

UPD1: I can access / without any problems

UPD2: I can access any page except pages which return index with model

UPD3: `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities().equals("ROLE_DEV") // true`

Comment: What is the error? Does your user has any of specified roles?

Comment: 403 forbidden. Role on user - ROLE_DEV.

Answer (score 0):

I've added `.csrf().disable()` in configure method and it helped me!